# Can't import python module in visual studio code

Tags: python, pip

The problem is that I can't import `SciencePlots` module(`couldn't be resolved` error), though I have it installed (I've looked through installed modules with `pip list` command). What may be the problem?
By the way, I work in a Visual Studio code.

Comment: You should use a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 0):

did you follow the instructions written here : [SciencePlot](https://pypi.org/project/SciencePlots/)

Check the warning section. Try to install the Scienceplot using Github:

> pip install git+https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots